# How do I allow privileged commands to fail but respond?

Tags: command-line, path, gentoo, privileges

I am reading up on several commands, some of which are privileged and some that may or may not be installed.  My system (gentoo) will respond with command not found sometimes when the program in the system.  How do I match the behavior of something like emerge?

Example of behavior I would like:

```
$ emerge -av mypackage
This action requires superuser access...
```

What I currently have:

```
$ lspci
bash: lspci: command not found
$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: ...
```

I would even prefer a "permission denied" message so I know that I should try to use sudo.  Of course I don't want to be experimenting around running as root.

Comment: I would like to say that the reason that `lspci` is not found is because `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` are not in your `$PATH`.  However, my `lspci` is in /usr/bin and I can execute it as an unprivileged user.  Probably a better example would be `/sbin/ifconfig` which actually needs root permissions to do anything useful except list the interfaces.  The gist of what I am saying is that the commands that usually need root permissions are supposed to be placed in the sbin directories, and the sbin directories are not supposed to be in the PATH of underpriv users.

Comment: @umeboshi `lspci` and/or `lsusb` (can't remember which one..) do need root privileges for some options. The default (no parameter) output does run fine as a normal user though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory containing `lspci` is likely not in your PATH.

You can find its location using `sudo -i which lspci` and add the directory to your path.

The likely locations are `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`

To add them you your current PATH, you can run (in a Bourne-based shell) `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

To make the change permanent, add the export command to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` (assuming you are using `bash` as a shell)

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but lspci is in `/usr/bin` on my system and doesn't need root privileges.  Also it's generally not good to add the sbin's to a underpriv's PATH.  The sudo command will do that for you if `/etc/sudoers` is configured correctly.  The whole purpose of the `sbin` directories is to separate the commands that need root from the other commands.

Comment: if lpsci is not on the user's path, 
`sudo which lpsci` will not show you the path, since the PATH is defined in root profile that sudo do not load in this notation.
Assuming lpsci is present in the system and  is available for root session, the way to know its path for user is `su -l -c '$(which lpsci)'`

 to know the path to

Comment: Keeping `{,/usr}/sbin/` out of the PATH doesn't do anything for security (unless using a restricted shell) - the user can run the command manually anyway (using a full path). I would not add them to the start of `$PATH` though, since `/sbin` traditionally contained potentially limited version of commands, in case `/usr` doesn't mount. On RHEL5, `lspci` is in `/sbin/lspci`.

Comment: @Tagwint: It does work for me however... (Tested on RHEL6) I'm assuming that if the PATH changes to allow running `lspci` with sudo, it will change for `which` run from sudo as well... (Yours does seem like a more generic solution..) (`su` tend to have different password requirements, which is problematic on systems without root passwords..) (`sudo -i` might be easier for `sudo` users)

Comment: @Gert van den Berg
your assumption is right, but I guess just sudo does not change the PATH.
That's default behavior of sudo which may be modified.

Perhaps in your case the command is available on path for the user already thus sudo does not hide it

Comment: This setting in `/etc/sudoers` likely did it on my test system `Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`, possibly with `Defaults env_reset`

Comment: Keeping root utilities in the sbins has nothing to do with security, yet everything to do with organization and clarity.  When the system designer/package maintainer/etc places an executable in /sbin, this person is effectively stating that this executable should normally be run as root and underprivileged users have no need to execute this utility.  When you start merging the bins and sbins, you wind up having to answer questions like this on stackexchange.

Comment: @umeboshi Interesting... (I'm normally an Arch user, where [someone decided it is a good idea](https://mailman.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2012-March/022625.html) to merge `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin`...) (Semi-related: Solaris have `/bin` as a link to `/usr/bin`, but it also have hundereds of `/usr/*/{s,}bin` directories) The annoying part is that several `/sbin` utilities are quite functional for non-root users. (And packagers mainly control where things go, likely within a policy though)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg  I have been noticing some of this "merging" in recent years where it would not have happened before.  I actually used to have `/usr` as a separate nfs export for diskless systems years ago, and I have come across information that distributions are wanting to change the `FHS` and remove the requirement that `/usr` be mountable later, claiming that the historical reasoning behind this is obsolete.  However this requirement is a product of the hardware available to the machine, which may change in the future for certain platforms.  It may one day become a good idea again.

Answer (score 1):

`lspci` isn't found because it isn't on an ordinary user's command search path. Commands that can only rarely or never be used effectively by non-root users are placed in one of the directories `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` or `/usr/local/sbin`, which are in root's command search path but not on other users'.

You can configure what bash does when a command is not found by defining a function called [`command_not_found_handle`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Search-and-Execution). So you can put something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
  if [[ -x "/sbin/$1" || -x "/usr/sbin/$1" || -x "/usr/local/sbin/$1" ]]; then
    echo 1>&2 "bash: $1: command not found, but can be executed as root"
  fi
  return 127
}
```